# Serverless new stage to use existing resources and only deploy the api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to create new stages for the `feature-branches` test.
but the problem is that when I am deploying the new stage `sls --deploy -s FEATURE`
it's creating everything in the serverless configuration. (I tried to find maybe an option in the resources to skip if exists. but didn't find any.)

When I am creating a new env it's failed because when I try to point to an existing resource it's said that it cannot be created.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option to skip existing resources in Serverless Framework.
One option would be splitting the resources that you want to share into a separately deployed service.